# Fine-Grained Political Modern Map of Italy

Tags: data, italy

Italy is made out of regions which are broken down into provinces and each city belongs to a province (each province also has a city with the same name as the province).

There are several road maps on the market but neither provides the breakdown I'm looking for (and to my knowledge google doesn't either).

Can someone please point out a place where I may download such a political modern map (or android or pc app that does this, or a book with the delineations I'm tslking about)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find them here: [Global Administrative Areas](http://www.gadm.org/country)

They provide free maps even up to community level.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but what format should I download and what software do I need to view these on an Android phone?

Comment: You can download KMZ files for Google Earth, this one should work

Comment: Thanks. So I've downloaded the four files ITA_adm {0,1,2,3}.kdz from the site you specified with Google Chrome for Android and opened the Google Earth app. Now what? How do I view the data pertaining to Italy's political subdivisions? Thanks.

Comment: I've tried clicking one of the files to open it in Google Earth but the app became unresponsive (ANR) on a Samsung Galaxy SIII 4.4.2 OS. Does this mean I csn only view the political data from a (faster) PC?

Comment: KMZ is a compressed KML file, using standard ZIP format. Almost every file explore or zip-program can unzip it. Perhaps then it is faster.

Comment: I've just had a look at the admin boundaries and they are very detailed - so the issue might be the amount of memory needed. You might want to consider downloading a GIS package onto a "faster" PC and using that as your starting point (QGIS, for example).                                                          Also, are you wanting to show data associated with the boundaries (i.e. political party) as well as just viewing the boundaries?

Comment: All these took me only two Minutes using Google: [Natural Earth](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-cultural-vectors/), [Mapcruzin](http://www.mapcruzin.com/free-italy-arcgis-maps-shapefiles.htm), [Diva-GIS](http://www.diva-gis.org/gdata), [GeoFabrik](http://download.geofabrik.de/europe/italy.html)