# Overlaying city and borough names with political boundaries in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, administrative-boundaries, geonames

This question is related to [Fine-Grained Political Modern Map of Italy](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/151662).

The following images are from  @Weinfried's answer. I was able to get the ITA_adm0.kmz, ITA_adm1.kmz, ITA_adm2.kmz, but not ITA_adm3.kmz, which for some reason does not open (I extracted these prior to importing them into QGIS). However, I don't know how to view the city names from Google Maps or other source in QGIS. Can someone please help me out?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could add **Labels** to your layer which shows the values of fields. If your layer already has an attribute field containing city/borough names, you can:

- *Double-click* the layer to access the **Layer Properties**
- Select the *Labels* tab
- Select the *"Label this layer with"* option (if you're using QGIS 2.8)
- Select the field which contains the names of your city/borough (I used the field `name` as I downloaded the .kmz file from [gadm](http://www.gadm.org/download))

[image: Italy with labels]